# Usage patterns/use cases for DI or when to start using it

Tags: dependency-injection, domain-object

I'm not sure for which use cases one should to use DI in the application. I know that injecting services like `PlaceService` or `CalculationService` etc fits very well but should I also create my domain objects with DI like a `User`? What is if the `User` has only one constructor which requires a first and lastname. Is this solveable with DI?

Should I use DI to create the instances for Set/List interfaces or is this pure overkill?

I use guice primarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule I use is, in general, to favor dependency injection, except where the object can be constructed with purely primitive values and there is no / a minimal chance that the object might be replaced by another implementation.

However, for domain objects, particularly if your objects do not constitute an [anemic domain model](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html), i.e., where objects are just bags of getters and setters, it can be useful to have objects that, for example, can persist themselves to a datastore, etc. For those sort of objects, dependency injection and [Salve](http://code.google.com/p/salve/) can be a powerful combination.

Guice has a specific solution to the type of problem posed by objects like your User object called [AssistedInject](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AssistedInject), though similar things are also possible with other lightweight containers or using something the builder or adapter patterns.

Answer (score 4):

The answer by ig0774 is a good starting point. In addition, I would like to offer this rule of thumb:

In the terminology of [Domain-Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215), you should DI for **services**, but not for *entities* or *value objects*.

In other words, DI fits well with conceptually long-lived, stateless objects of which there are usually one or a known number in use.